# DRF PUT Partial Update returning Not Found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get to grips with Django and DRF but having some trouble. I would like to make a PUT request to make a partial update on a record.

I currently have the following parts -

From models.py

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    # Link to User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    joindate = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

From api/views.py

```
class MyUserDetailUpdateView(GenericAPIView, UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserPartialUpdateSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user'

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

From api/serializers.py

```
class MyUserPartialUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
```

From urls.py

```
url(r'^api/userupdate/(?P<user>[\w]+)/$', apiviews.MyUserDetailUpdateView.as_view(), name='my_user_detail_view_api')
```

For testing I used httpie and try -

```
http -v PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userupdate/johndoe/ first_name="Johnny"
```

The server side is reporting a "Not Found: /api/userdate/johndoe/" and returns a HTTP 404 to the client.

What am I missing to do a partial update?

Thanks

Comment: You should pass primary key in url, in your case it's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyUser.user` is supposed to be a `User` instance. You can't use it that way.

You likely want the `MyUser` associated with the `username`. In that case, the argument you want to extra from url will be set as `lookup_url_kwarg` and the `lookup_field` will do the join across the related model:

```
class MyUserDetailUpdateView(GenericAPIView, UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserPartialUpdateSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'user'
```

Comment: In addition to this I also needed to add fields = '__all__' to my serializer.